# How to stop python from reading regex from a string

Tags: python

When I run this in python:

```
print "\bin\example.exe"
```

it prints

[image]

I think this is because the "\b" is being picked up as a regular expression.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use double backslash (i.e., ` \\ ` instead of ` \ `).

Comment: try `print r"\bin\example.exe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escape the backslashes with backlashes

```
print "\\bin\\example.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks! All the comments and answers worked but you were first.

Comment: Look at @AER's answer. It is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about the \b being the issue, it is using \ as the escape character.

There are two ways of dealing with backslashes in Python:

- The first is to use a double back slash `"\\"` which prints as `\`; and
- The second is to put a r before the string to everything is printed as written such as `r"asdf\jk"` which  will print `asdf\jk`.

Answer (score 2):

You would generally escape out `\` with an extra `\`.
So your string would be

```
>>> print "\\bin\\example.exe"
\bin\example.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

You need double backslashes `\\` otherwise python thinks they are escape sequences:

```
print "\\bin\\example.exe"
```

[Look here for more information on string literals and escape sequences.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)